# Categories for the Working Mathematician, Exercise IV.04.01

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

I have to prove that:

(1) Any two skeletons $C_0$ and $C_0'$ of a category $C$ are isomorphic;

(2) If $A_0$ is a skeleton of $A$ and $C_0$ a skeleton of $C$, then $A$ and $C$ are equivalent if and only if $A_0$ and $C_0$ are isomorphic.

If I got the idea correctly, the sketch of what I need to do is:

(1) For each object $c$ in $C_0$, let $F(c)$ be the object in $C_0'$ isomorphic to $c$, let $\varphi(c)$ be an isomorphism $c \to F(c)$, and for each arrow $f: c \to c'$ in $C_0$, let $$F(f) = \varphi(c') \circ f \circ \varphi(c)^{-1}.$$ Then $F$ is an isomorphism between the skeletons.

(2) Given an equivalence $F: A \to C$, for each object $a$ in $A_0$, let $H(a)$ be the object in $C_0$ isomorphic to $F(a)$, let $\varphi(a)$ be an isomorphism $F(a) \to H(a)$, and for each arrow $f: a \to a'$ in $A_0$, let $$H(f) = \varphi(a') \circ F(f) \circ \varphi(a)^{-1}$$ (here I'm using that the inclusion from a skeleton is full). Then $H$ is going to be an isomorhism between the skeletons. Conversely, given an isomorphism $H: A_0 \to C_0$, for each object $a$ in $A$, given the object $a_0$ in $A_0$ isomorphic to $a$, let $F(a)=H(a_0)$, let $\varphi(a)$ be an isomorphism $a \to a_0$, and for each arrow $f: a \to a'$ in $A$, let $$F(f) = H(\varphi(a') \circ f \circ \varphi(a)^{-1})$$ (again, here I'm using the inclusion from a skeleton is full). Then $F$ is going to be an equivalence between the categories.

Right?

Comment: I haven't checked the details but this seems right; at least the idea is the right one

Comment: Exactly that's it.